# Powershell script to delete files not specified in a list

Tags: list, file, powershell, delete-file

I have a list of filenames in a text file like this:

```
f1.txt
f2
f3.jpg
```

How do I delete everything else from a folder except these files in Powershell?

Pseudo-code:

- Read the text file line-by-line
- Create a list of filenames
- Recurse folder and its subfolders
- If filename is not in list, delete it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Data:

```
-- begin exclusions.txt --
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
-- end --
```

Code:

```
# read all exclusions into a string array
$exclusions = Get-Content .\exclusions.txt

dir -rec *.* | Where-Object {
   $exclusions -notcontains $_.name } | `
   Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are happy with your results. `-WhatIf` shows you what it *would* do (i.e. it will not delete)

-Oisin

Comment: I like it.  Why not use -notcontains, though?

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for me. I tried with -notcontains as Mike suggested and the results are same.

Comment: i hate -notcontains. nah, only kidding. yeah, that's ever terser.

Comment: Since the results returned by `dir -rec *.*` are `FileInfo` instances, you can just use `$_.Name` to get the file name.  PowerShell converts the file to a string in order to call `[io.path]::GetFileName($_)`.

Comment: @EmperorXLII True, that.

Answer (score 6):

If the files exist in the current folder then you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -exclude (gc exclusions.txt) | Remove-Item -whatif
```

This approach assumes each file is on a separate line.  If the files exist in subfolders then I would go with Oisin's approach.

Comment: Yeah, files are on separate lines. Thanks for the answers. 

If the parent location has subfolders, I get a prompt saying "The item at Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::<<path>> has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with  the item. Are you sure you want to continue?" Probably adding the -recurse switch will fix it.

Oisin's approach doesn't cause this prompt.

Comment: If subdirs are involved then you do *not* want to use my approach and you don't want to use -r otherwise it will delete entire folders.

Answer (score 1):

actually this only seems to work for the first directory rather than recursing - my altered script recurses properly.

```
$exclusions = Get-Content .\exclusions.txt

dir -rec | where-object {-not($exclusions -contains [io.path]::GetFileName($_))} | `  
where-object {-not($_ -is [system.IO.directoryInfo])} | remove-item -whatif
```

Comment: I used $_.FullName.ToLower() instead of [io.path]::GetFileName($_) and used full path names in my exclusion list to get the recursion to work.