# PowerShell script to delete files from list and output list of deleted file

Tags: list, file, powershell, delete-file

I have a list of files including their location in a .txt like the following:

> \SERVER01\backupsFolder\xx\a\ss.bak 
>   \SERVER01\backupsFolder\xx\a\ss.bak 
>   \SERVER02\backupsFolder\yy\b\dd.bak 
>   \SERVER02\backupsFolder\yy\b\dd.bak

How do I delete everything else recursively starting from the 'backupsFolder' folder for example, and also output all the deleted files?

Comment: Everything else? So you want to delete everything **except** what is in the list?

Comment: @EBGreen That's right. Right now im creating a file list by folder. And run a script similar to the one in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009955/powershell-script-to-delete-files-not-specified-in-a-list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this should help.

Script:

```
$TargetFolder = “Pathofyourfolder”
$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Exclude (gc List.txt)  -Recurse
foreach ($File in $Files)
    { write-host “Deleting File $File” -foregroundcolor “Red”; Remove-Item $File | out-null }
```