# Powershell Script to delete files not in a list with progress bar

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, delete-file

I have a folder with .jpg files in it. I associate these with products in an access database. One of the sources for products provides these .jpg files but they do not allow you to easily download only the pictures that you currently use. Therefore I have found a PowerShell Script to delete the files that I do not need.

```
$exclusions = Get-Content C:\Users\office\Desktop\ExcludedPhotos.txt
dir -rec M:\PhotoDirectory\PhotoFolder | Where-Object {$exclusions -notcontains $_.name } | Remove-Item
```

Credit to @x0n [Powershell script to delete files not specified in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009955/powershell-script-to-delete-files-not-specified-in-a-list)

And it works great! but the problem is it takes forever and I have over 180,000 items to search through and delete. So I wanted to make a progress bar that would let me know how far I had gone through the process.

So after a little bit of searching I found an article called "using the progress bar"

The problem is I don't know how to mash the two together, However I have made an attempt here:

```
$exclusions = Get-Content C:\Users\office\Desktop\ExcludedPhotos.txt 
  1..100 | foreach-object {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "$_ %" -Id 1 -PercentComplete $_ -CurrentOperation "Deleting File $_"
       dir -rec M:\PhotoDirectory\PhotoFolder | Where-Object {$exclusions -notcontains $_.name } | Remove-Item
        }
```

However that seems to take even longer than the original script did, I don't know exactly how it is working, and I am testing it when I only need to remove 10-15 files.

It is likely there is something really basic I am missing But I would really appreciate some help understanding this.

Here I have added a screenshot:

[PowerShell Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WnCU.png)

Answer (score 5):

> However that seems to take even longer than the original script did

That's because you're attempting to enumerate, filter and delete the files 100 times - which is obviously unnecessary.

What you want to do is calculate how far in the process of deleting the files you are, and then use that as a basis for the percentage you pass to `Write-Progress`. The easiest way to keep count is probably to use a regular `for` loop:

<sup>Note: *these first two examples are very generic, go to the bottom for an example that takes your volume (~180.000 files) into account.*</sup>

```
# Grab all the files you need to delete
$exclusions = Get-Content C:\Users\office\Desktop\ExcludedPhotos.txt
$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem M:\PhotoDirectory\PhotoFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$exclusions -notcontains $_.Name }

for($i = 0; $i -lt $filesToDelete.Count; $i++){
    # calculate progress percentage
    $percentage = ($i + 1) / $filesToDelete.Count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Deleting File #$($i+1)/$($filesToDelete.Count)" -PercentComplete $percentage
    # delete file
    $filesToDelete[$i] |Remove-Item
}
# All done
Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Completed
```

---

Another characteristic you might want to use to indicate a percentage is the relative volume (total number of bytes) removed. We can do this by simply keeping track of how many bytes we need to remove total, and how many we've removed so far:

```
$exclusions = Get-Content C:\Users\office\Desktop\ExcludedPhotos.txt
$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem M:\PhotoDirectory\PhotoFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$exclusions -notcontains $_.Name }
$TotalSize = ($filesToDelete |Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
$BytesRemoved = 0

foreach($file in $filesToDelete){
    $percentage = $BytesRemoved / $TotalSize * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Deleted $BytesRemoved/$TotalSize bytes" -PercentComplete $percentage
    $file |Remove-Item
    $BytesRemoved += $file.Length
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Completed
```

---

As @MatthewWetmore points out, invoking `Write-Progress` every time you delete a file will of course incur some overhead. And with 180.000 files, you're probably not *that* interested in having the UI update when the progress goes from 3.56325% to 3.56331%

What you could do is use the `for` loop to count in increments of 1% of the entire set of items, and then remove a whole range of files on each iteration:

```
[int]$hundredthStep = $filesToDelete.Count / 100
for($i = 0; $i -lt $filesToDelete.Count; $i += $hundredthStep){
    # calculate progress percentage
    $percentage = ($i + 1) / $filesToDelete.Count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Deleting File up to #$($i+1)/$($filesToDelete.Count)" -PercentComplete $percentage
    # delete file
    $filesToDelete[$i..($i + $hundredthStep - 1)] |Remove-Item
}
# All done
Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Completed
```

Comment: If the files to delete count is extremely high, he'll also benefit from not writing progress with every file but instead every several.  For instance, dividing the count by 100, round up to the nearest int, and then using that as a modulus against a counter.  E.g.  With 1-100 files, you'll write progress with every file.  With 200, every other file.  With 1000, every 10...

Comment: Additionally I've seen recursive get-item on an extremely large tree is super slow.  I've had better luck with  get-item -recurse -directory, then iteratively get-item -file.  I've written variations on this for validating OS VHDs or WIM contents.

Comment: "That's because you're attempting to enumerate, filter and delete the files 100 times - which is obviously unnecessary." that makes sense of course it would take longer as I am trying to have it run through the entire script 100 times and giving myself a progress bar to tell me when it is done repeating itself. I like the option where it calculates the total bytes removed. I am going to try that and come back with my findings.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Good point, appropriated the first example to count in 1% increments

Comment: @MatthewWetmore works as well, but then you execute the loop body 180000 times vs 100 times :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I was editing the example, then saw your comment.  The body is where the individual work goes.  Same O(n), just a different way of unrolling the work.  You do a pipeline, the Remove-Item could be the replacement of DoTheOtherThing.   Here's the all in one example I was editing:  `function DoTheProgress { param($i) $i } function DoTheOtherThing {}$count = 180000; $mod = $count/100;  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++) { if (0 -eq ($i % $mod)) { DoTheProgress $i }; DoTheOtherThing}`  Naturally adapt naming and such, just an example.

Comment: Hi all, I tried both of the original examples, and they worked beautifully for deleting the files but I have not seen a progress bar. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but the only way I can see it is done is by watching task manager.

Comment: @Liberator17 How exactly are you running your scripts? Can you show us a screenshot/gif?

Comment: I have edited the post and included a link at the end to the picture. @MatthewWetmore

Comment: @Liberator17 Eh... It's not that weird that you're not seeing any progress bar - you're not using `Write-Progress` or any of the code I've provided in your screenshot?

Comment: Wow, That was embarrassing, I have uploaded the correct screenshot. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something like this (beware this is untested so i've put `-whatif` on the remove cmdlet which you should remove when you're happy it's working correctly):

```
$exclusions = Get-Content C:\Users\office\Desktop\ExcludedPhotos.txt 
$files = dir -rec M:\PhotoDirectory\PhotoFolder | Where-Object {$exclusions -notcontains $_.name } 

$files | foreach-object {
    $num += 1    
    Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "$_ %" -Id 1 -PercentComplete (($num / $files.count) * 100)  -CurrentOperation "Deleting File $($_.name)"
    $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```